# how can i query count in function with parameter that will change according to user?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-development-server

```
public function totalmember($designation){
    $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalmember FROM users 
    WHERE designation = :designation");
    $stmt->bindParam(':designation', $designation, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $count = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    echo $count->totalmember;
}
```

what i want is when people are logged in their respective account i want people to know how many people from their respective designation(teacher,clerk,peon ) have account?

Comment: Please, take an example and share your output you want to reach to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the **fetchAll()** function instead of **fetch()**.
Here is the reference link.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: using fetchAll the error is something like  Notice: Trying to get property 'totalmember' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Does that work?

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE designation = :designation");
$stmt->bindParam(':designation', $designation, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$count = $result->rowCount();
echo $count;

$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM users WHERE designation = :designation");
$stmt->bindParam(':designation', $designation, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo $count;
```

Comment: it does not work either.but if i gave specific designation in the query it gives the result i.e `$stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM users WHERE designation = 'teacher' ");` it works perfectly.